# flatpickr not loading rails 6 + webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, flatpickr

I'm trying to use flatpickr with Rails 6 but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

I've done the following:
`yarn add flatpickr`

and in my files I have the following:
`packs/application.js`

```js
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
import * as ActiveStorage from '@rails/activestorage';
import 'channels';

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

import('jquery');
import('tooltip-js');
import('../components/main.js');
import('../components/lib_ext.js');
import('../components/dialog.js');
import('../components/widgets.js');
import('../components/classes.js');
import('../components/payroll.js');
import('../components/account_context_menu.js');
import('../components/plan_table.js');
import('../components/requirements.js');
import('../components/help.js');
import('../components/help_data.js');
import('../components/scripts.js'); // nav js
import('../components/additional.js');
import('../components/effects.js');
import('../components/consolidated_orders');
import('../components/sales_invoices.js');
import('../components/journals/auto_reversal.js');
import('../components/budgets/new.js');
import('../components/budgets/export.js');
import('../components/new.js');

import('../stylesheets/application.scss');
const images = require.context('../images', true)

// flatpickr
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr'
require("flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css");

flatpickr("[data-behavior='flatpickr']", {
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "F j, Y",
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
});
```

and in my form, I have the following

```
<%= f.text_field :company_year_end, data: { behavior: 'flatpickr' } %>
```

The result here is that the picker doesn't show at all. Looking in the console I don't see any errors relating to flatpickr.

Answer (score 2):

Got it, had to load using turbolinks

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  flatpickr("[data-behavior='flatpickr']", {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  });
})
```